# iOS Universal Links don't work as expected - always opens no matter the path

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

So I stumbled upon an issue using iOS universal links.

let's assume my domain is: example.com.

So I set the associated domains to be applinks:example.com

Then, in the apple-app-site-association file, I specified the following:

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "XXXXXXX.com.example.bro",
        "paths": [
          "/ios/*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And I expected only links that end with /ios will make the app open, while other links, such as example.com, example.com/something, should open in Safari.

However, every link under the domain example.com opens in the app.

I tried using "NOT *", "NOT /", "NOT /*" and so on, with no success.

What could I be missing?

Help would be much appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like your apple-app-site-association file is correct. FYI:- If all paths opening in-app. you can validate the path in AppDelegate and use UIApplication.shared.openURL() to open a non-supported URL in safari.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

It appears I had conflicting files which caused these issues.
Apparently, my teammate added a similar file under ./well_known. Which seem to have taken precedence over the file I added. (The file under ./well_known had an asterisk * - allowing all links).

Once I removed the extra file under ./well_known, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that finds themselves here I found that the app itself seemed to cache which URLs to load in-app.

I initially had paths set to `*` in my apple-app-site-association file.

After changing the apple-app-site-association file to limit it to specific routes, I had to uninstall and re-install my app for the changes to take effect.